XAMPP apache web server openssl Certificate Error
i installed a SSL certificate on my server from Godaddy and it is working fine on browsers with secure sign. how ever when trying to access my site from stream, the below error occurred.

file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

is there anything i missed on XAMPP apache configuration i should look for?
i already enabled openssl extension and set directory to certificates on php.ini
Thanks in advance.

Did you install the intermediate certificates properly? Are your OS root certificates up to date?

@Sammitch, they are installed properly, i guess that's why certificate is working on browsers. and root certificates are up to date as far as i know. is there a way i can check whether they're updated or not? i am using windows server 2019.

Most browsers ship with a huge number of intermediate certificates baked-in which can obscure this issue, while other apps and devices will fail. Did you install just the youdomain.com certificate, or did you install the GoDaddy's intermediate certs as well?

installed both of them.
